# Best way to create a disk-based B-tree from a given file?

Tags: search, data-structures, indexing

Do you know a fast algorithm to create a B-tree from an existing (non-sorted) file containing space separated integers. Typically, the size of the file will be orders of magnitude bigger than the available RAM.

You can assume that the B-tree will not be modified afterwards, i.e. it will be only used to index the info in the file (say the file contains comma separated strings).
Moreover, is a B-tree the best idea to use for an index, can you suggest other structures?

Comment: Vague question. What kind of queries would you be running? And even more vague when you 'seek' the 'best'.

Comment: Good remark, assume that the file contains integers and I only want to check if an integer is contained in the file or not, i. e. I want to use the B-tree as a simple look-up index.

Comment: Why not use a hashtable?

Comment: I agree with viksit- it sounds like a hashtable is what you want. Is there a reason you want to use a B-tree?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you want to access your data. If you are using a hashtable, you can only access elements by their primary key in O(1) which is faster than with a tree(log(n))

You cannot select ranges (everything string in between say 10 and 20) which is supported by tree algorithms in Log(n) where as a hash index can result in a full scan O(n). also the constant overhead of hash indexes is usually bigger (which is no factor in theta notation, but it still exists) whereas tree algorithms are usually easier to maintain, grow with data, scale, etc.

Use a hash table if you do not need ordering and a binary tree(balanced) otherwise.